# enumeration with many items

Tags: lists, list-order

How do you say the following correctly:

> The athlete goes swimming, then cycling, running, taking a shower and relaxing, in that order.

So in a long sentence, if I do not want to state *then* after each comma, can I use *in that order* at the end, or does that sound weird?

Comment: "The athlete goes swimming, cycling, running, **takes** a shower and then **relaxes**, in that order". But you don't even need to say "in that order" because it is already clear.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks a lot!